# Object counter in C++ using Constructor and Destructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, count, destructor

So, I'm new here, if I make any mistakes please bear with me.

I'm a college student learning C++ and new to constructors and destructors.

What I want to do is: I need to create a program which maintains a real-time count of objects, i.e, whenever an object of that class is created or destroyed, the object counter is incremented/decremented respectively and displayed (that's my logic anyways, suggestions would make me grateful).

That meant creating a static variable, and I cooked up this:

```
class objectCount
{
    protected:
    static int count;

    public:
    objectCount()
    {
        count++;
        cout<<"Object of type class created. \nNo. of objects of type class currently: "<<count<<endl;
    }

    ~objectCount()
    {
        count--;
        cout<<"Latest object of type class deleted. \nNo. of objects of type class currently: "<<count<<endl;
    }
};

int objectCount::count=0;

void main()
{
    int ch;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"--------------- || OBJECT COUNTER || ----------------"<<endl;

    do {
        cout<<"1. Create Object\n2. Delete Object\n3.Exit";
        cout<<endl<<"Enter your choice: ";
        cin>>ch;

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: objectCount();
                break;

            case 2: ~objectCount();
                break;

            case 3: break;

            default: cout<<endl<<"Invalid Choice.";
                break;
        };
    }while(ch!=3);
    getch();
}
```

So, I thought I was all geared up and ready to go, but then TurboC(yes my college forces us to use TC, and I will hence have no other option BUT to use it aswell) gave me an error(Illegal structure operation) at the "Case 2: ~objectCounter();" part. I went through the books and realized I forgot constructors need an object declaration too. (objectCount OC;)

But now I'm confused as to how exactly to change the code to make it work.

I need it so that based upon user choice, an object is created, no. of objects updated and printed, else object deleted, no. of objects printed and updated, and exit when done.

I searched around, but usually people posting examples just declare finite number of objects like "objectCount c1; objectCount c2;" and be done with it, which isn't really my case.

Could any of you, the esteemed, kind, gently and knowledgeable community help me, please?

**EDIT:** Ideal output:

```
--------------- || OBJECT COUNTER || ----------------
1. Create Object
2. Delete Object
3. Exit
Enter your choice:  1
Object of type class created. 
No. of objects of type class currently: 1 //Static variable incremented & displayed here.

1. Create Object
2. Delete Object
3. Exit
Enter your choice:  1
Object of type class created. 
No. of objects of type class currently: 2 //Static variable incremented & displayed here.

1. Create Object
2. Delete Object
3. Exit
Enter your choice:  2
Object of type class deleted 
No. of objects of type class currently: 1 //Static variable decremented & displayed here.

1. Create Object
2. Delete Object
3. Exit
Enter your choice:  3
```

**Edit 2**: I guess I'll just use an array of 100 objects as suggested by besc, should work for now.

But thanks everyone for your answers, and yes I'll definitely go beyond TC and learn the real deal.

Comment: It should be `int main`

Comment: _"yes my college forces us to use TC, and I will hence have no other option BUT to use it aswell"_ Just be sure to later take a class in _actual_ C++ before you go looking for a job in professional software development.

Comment: _"I searched around, but usually people posting examples just declare finite number of objects like "objectCount c1(); objectCount c2();" and be done with it, which isn't really my case"_ Those are function declarations, not objects.

Comment: _"But now I'm confused as to how exactly to change the code to make it work."_ A vector? When the user presses '1', add a new object to the vector. When the user presses '2', remove an object from the vector. It's quite contrived and you haven't stated your requirements very well, so we can't give you a proper answer. Your reference counting is almost right, at least, although you've forgotten about copy constructors.

Comment: What is a vector? Also, just need a simple program which increments the count variable whenever the constructor is called, and decrements the count whenever destructor is called, but the user should be able to perform as many object creation/deletion tasks he wants to do.

Comment: What is the actual point of using TurboC++ to teach in 2017... Modern compilers are free.

Comment: @DeiDei Exactly what I thought, but my State Board of Education demands it, and so I'm stuck with the blue screen and void main(). Although I guess it's because we have "Computer Graphics" as a subject with makes use of the graphics.h header file, which, correct me if wrong, isn't in modern compilers. Correct me if wrong, I'm just repeating what I read on the internet somewhere long time before.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"Those are function declarations, not objects." Yeah my bad I didn't notice that when typing out my question, thanks, I'll edit that :)

Comment: _"Although I guess it's because we have "Computer Graphics" as a subject with makes use of the graphics.h header file, which, correct me if wrong, isn't in modern compilers"_ Correct - modern compilers have support for _actual_ graphics tools, not command-line mimickery for 1980s versions of DOS. The mind boggles that your State Board of Education can be _so_ stupid.

Comment: _"What is a vector"_ Now it's time to Google `c++ vector`.

Comment: _"just need a simple program which increments the count variable whenever the constructor is called, and decrements the count whenever destructor is called, but the user should be able to perform as many object creation/deletion tasks he wants to do"_ Right, then you should do what I said.

Comment: It hasn't really been mentioned: You should NOT call the destructor manually. Using regular objects (no new and delete), the destructor will be called when the object goes out of scope. If you call it yourself before then, it will be called twice, which is super duper bad news.

Comment: Yep, I can't use vectors in my program, because they're out-of-syllabus and out-of-scope, and my program will certainly be rejected if I used them. No offense meant to you, it's just that I will have to work with age-old techniques and resources. I'm limited by certain restrictions and am desperate to work within them. Any way around the vector, or will I have to stick with finite objects?

Comment: Someone -1'ed the question, and now I hate myself. Did I ask this question in the wrong place?

Comment: @AsquareM35's Dont worry about the TC being old. Just focus on the concepts for now and try switching to using codeblocks or visual studio on your own. They have nice visual code editors and will make your code reading and editing easy and wont affect much of the code change for your beginner level. You have to learn a few good things on your own.

Comment: @Ahmed.J Yeah, thanks mate. I have used code::blocks and Visuak Studio for Unity, and they are much better. But yeah, I dunno what to do about this program :/

Comment: @AsquareM35,s one thing to know is that destructors dont destroy anything they are just that function that are called when an object is about to get destroyed. Now what you are trying to do is create objects but dont have any variable to access them. you dont know how many objects will be created so you cant use a fixed size array to store these objects. You need resizeable array. Vectors are just that array which can be resized. So without vectors or similar, pointers, new delete keywords you wont get your ideal output. Hnau just showed you how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: you don't need to call destructor explicitly because it will be called automatically as soon as the object goes out of scope. also you cannot access `non-static data` without an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of the counting logic is correct (as long as you stay in a single-threaded scenario), but your `main()` is not.

In the switch in `case 1` what you’re doing is creating an unnamed temporary `objectCount` object that immediately gets destroyed again. You’ll see the ctor getting called immediately followed by a call to the dtor. Why does it get destroyed immediately? Because you didn’t give it a name. So, that’s not particularly useful, but valid; although it’s clearly not what you intended.

`case 2` does not compile because you call the dtor without an object. There’s actually two problems here.

**(1)**
The dtor needs to know which `objectCount` object it is supposed to destroy. In that regard it acts like any other non-static member function. This would work:

```
// Creates an object, ctor gets called.
objectCount obj;

// Calls the destructor on obj.
// DO NOT DO THIS! See (2).
obj.~objectCount();
```

**(2)**
In C++ there are only very few cases where you call a dtor explicitly. As long as you’re in the early stages of learning C++ they are not relevant. So it’s a valid rule to say: If you call a dtor explicitly you’re doing it wrong. Dtors are called implictly when an object dies. How that death occurs depends on where your object is allocated.

On the stack:

```
void func() {
    objectCount obj;
} // obj goes out of scope here: dtor is called
```

On the heap:

```
objectCount* obj = new objectCount;
// ...
delete obj; // dtor is called
```

Whenever possible prefer the stack because manual memory management with new/delete is extremely error prone.

As you can see in the stack example, a scope is defined by curly braces. If you need finer grained control over an object’s lifetime, you can use a set of “standalone” curlies. I.e. your `main()` could look like this:

```
//...

do {
    cout << "1. Create/destroy on the stack\n"
    cout << "2. Create/destroy on the heap\n
    cout << "3.Exit";
    cout<<endl<<"Enter your choice: ";
    cin>>ch;

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: {
            {
                // Note the standalone set of curlies.
                objectCount obj;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            objectCount* obj = new objectCount;
            delete obj;
            break;
        }

        case 3: break;

        default: cout<<endl<<"Invalid Choice.";
            break;
    };
}while(ch!=3);

// ...
```

To keep your user-choices to create and destroy explicitly you need to use new/delete here. There is no suitable scope that could provide the same effect. But before you do, think about the things that could wrong. For example, what would happen if the user decides to create twice in a row ... or delete twice in a row.

**Edit:**

To let the user create and destroy an arbitrary number of objects, you need to hold on to a list containing the existing objects, a.k.a `std::vector`. At that point TurboC becomes a real problem because it predates the C++ standard template library (STL), which vector is a part of. And you do not want to implement vector yourself at this point.

Let me just say how mindbogglingly braindead your State Board of Education’s decicion is to force an IDE from the DOS era on you. You will not learn any useful C++ that way. If you’re doing C++ just for the credit, get through it and then forget about the experience. But if you’re interested in the language at all, get yourself a modern compiler and IDE  and do some real C++ in your own time. It doesn’t really matter what you choose: the free edition of Visual Studio, Clang or GCC with Qt Creator, Eclipse, CLion: anything will play in a completely different universe than TurboC. [*sigh* Feeling better now that that’s off my chest ;).]

OK, how to solve your immediate problem? Make it simpler. Use a C-style fixed-length array of owning pointers to the created objects and a variable that holds the current number of allocated objects.

```
// ... in main() outside the loop ...
// 100 objects should be enough for everybody :)
// DO NOT DO THIS IN REAL C++! Use std::vector instead!
objectCount* object_ptrs[100];
int current_max_idx = 0;
```

Now you can use `new`/`delete` to create and destroy up to 100 objects, incrementing and decrementing `current_max_idx` along the way. Make sure to `delete` all remaining objects when your program exits and keep in mind that arrays are zero-based, i.e. `object_ptrs` has index 0 through 99.

Also consider removing the counting logic from your ctor and dtor. It’s redundant because the `current_max_idx` variable does the same job and printing on creation/destruction can happen in the `switch`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! _"For example, what would happen if the user decides to create twice in a row ... or delete twice in a row."_  - That is what I want the user to be able to do. E.g. He creates an object, o/p: "Object created, no. Of objects currently: 1". He creates another, o/p "Object created, no. of objects currently: 2". He now decides to delete, o/p: "Object deleted, no. of objects currently active: 1". That kind of thing.

Comment: Added ideal output in answer

Comment: Amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was considering somethin like that but wondered if there was a way to truely give infinite chances to the user, though will have to end up doing that. Mindboggling it is to me too, that TC is forced upon us. Although yes, I passionately do want to learn game coding, like Unity w/ C#, upto the point I'm 100% perfect in my knowledge of it. I do have N++ hooked up with MinGW as a modern option and I do coding in it. (Although rarely cuz I don't get enough time). Anyways, I'm deeply grateful to you to bear with me & my situations & give me a feasible solution. I'll learn bout vectors too

Comment: I have in fact enrolled in a Complete Unity Development Course and created a simple text-based "Guess the Number" game so far, in which the game decides a no. bet 0-100, and gives you hints based on your guesses to help you guess what no. it is. I added some code of my own(other than what was shown in the tuts) and closed any loose ends and covered up all possible errors and scenarios. Made me realise C# in VS is much more fun than printf on a DOS Prompt screen. P.S. I hope me commenting this isn't illegal under some restriction of self-advertisement clause of SO.

Comment: But thanks again though, you gave the best, most comprehensive, and the most complete answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

The problem with `~objectCount()` is essentially that it says "delete the objectCount object"... and the compiler says "which one?" If you don't somehow keep track of the objects you create, you're probably memory-leaking those objects.

Instead of directly calling the constructor and destructor, I'd recommend using the `new` and `delete` keywords. Those operate on objectCount pointers, so for example, you could have code like:

```
objectCount * my_object = new objectCount(); // allocates memory, calls constructor
delete my_object; // calls destructor, frees memory
```

That's how to memory-manage a single objectCount object. To keep many of those objects around, you'll probably want to maintain an array or `std::vector` of those pointers.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you **do not use `new` and `delete`**. _"That's how to memory-manage a single objectCount object"_ No, it's not. Maybe it was in 1985!

Comment: @Lightness: How else would you dynamically create and destroy single objects? Yes, of course you *could* store `objectCount` instances in some container, and remove/destroy/pop them off again. But wouldn't that distract from the lesson at hand?

Comment: @Lightness: A `unique_ptr` has those very same features of that make it harder to understand, what's going on. It's a fine tool if you know what you're doing. But if you're just learning, it's going to offer distraction with no clear benefit.

Comment: @IInspectable: Erm no RAII makes it much easier to manage and to understand, and largely removes the risk of messing up. `new`/`delete` are now advanced features.

Comment: @Lightness: Without understanding the risks of manual memory management, you will have a pretty hard time understanding, what automatic memory management buys you. Manual memory management teaches you two important lessons: `1` It's tedious and easy to mess up. `2` It is, what automatic memory management uses internally.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes those are important lessons, to be had at a later stage of learning. You learn to drive before you learn to service a car.